# How I get Attribute using by XMLPull parser

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-xmlpullparser

I have an xml file and I show the small part of it, to show the content what I want

```
<media:content medium="image" url="http://msnbcmedia.msn.com/j/MSNBC/Components/Photo/_new/111010-romney-health-4p.thumb.jpg">
                <media:credit role="provider">Getty Images file</media:credit>
                <media:copyright>2010 Getty Images</media:copyright>
                <media:text><![CDATA[<p><a href="http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/44854320/ns/politics-decision_2012/"><img align="left" border="0" src="http://msnbcmedia.msn.com/j/MSNBC/Components/Photo/_new/111010-romney-health-4p.thumb.jpg" alt="Mitt Romney speaks at the National Press Club March 5, 2010 in Washington, D.C." style="margin:0 5px 5px 0" /></a></p><br clear="all" />]]></media:text>
            </media:content>
```

Now I want to retrieve the URL tab. How I do this

I do the following code

```
if(parser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("media:content"))
{
    Log.d("media count-->",parser.getAttributeCount()+"");
}
```

So this gives me -1.

Hey if anyone give me hint for how i can get the image url.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Call [getAttributeValue](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#getAttributeValue%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) like the following

```
parser.getAttributeValue(null, "url")
```

inside of your if statement. Make sure `getEventType()` is equal to START_TAG since your current if statement will also evaluate to true when your parser is set to the END_TAG portion of your media:content (which would give you a -1 attribute count).

**EDIT** 
Since you are having so much trouble, I hope this little test function does what you want:

```
public void parseXml() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
{
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
    parser.setInput(new StringReader(
            "<media:content medium=\"image\" url=\"http://msnbcmedia.msn.com/j/MSNBC/Components/Photo/_new/111010-romney-health-4p.thumb.jpg\">"
                    + "<media:credit role=\"provider\">Getty Images file</media:credit>"
                    + "<media:copyright>2010 Getty Images</media:copyright>"
                    + "<media:text><![CDATA[<p><a href=\"http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/44854320/ns/politics-decision_2012/\"><img align=\"left\" border=\"0\" src=\"http://msnbcmedia.msn.com/j/MSNBC/Components/Photo/_new/111010-romney-health-4p.thumb.jpg\" alt=\"Mitt Romney speaks at the National Press Club March 5, 2010 in Washington, D.C.\" style=\"margin:0 5px 5px 0\" /></a></p><br clear=\"all\" />]]></media:text>"
                    + "</media:content>"));

    while (!"media:content".equals(parser.getName()) && parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        parser.next();
    }
    Log.d("media count -->", parser.getAttributeValue(null, "url"));
}
```

Comment: have you any other method to do it

Comment: That's the correct method to do it. Did you change your if statement to also check the event type of the parser? Also, are you sure you are reading the correct XML?

Comment: This is one of the few cases where the order of the `equals()`is important. Make sure you use `"constant".equals(parser.getName())` instead of the other way around or you *will* get null pointer exceptions...

Answer (score 3):

```
private String readLink(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "enclosure");
    final String link = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "url");
    return link;
}
```

This works for me in android with XmlPullParser.