# Android get custom R.xml attribute

Tags: android

I have a file in R.xml.test that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<scale factor="1.00" />    
</resources>
```

What is the proper way to fetch the `scale factor` attribute?

I am thinking something like:

```
InputStream inputStream = resources.getAssets().open("test.xml");        
 XmlPullParserFactory xmlPullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();             xmlPullParserFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
xmlResourceParser = xmlPullParserFactory.newPullParser(); xmlResourceParser.setInput(inputStream, "UTF-8");'
```

Comment: What do you mean by `R.xml.test` file?

Comment: Its an android thing..Frome base project it is /res/xml/test.xml

Comment: @lmma wake R.xml is your gen file or any other file is this?

Comment: yes it is. From the project folder /res/xml/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refs [How I get Attribute using by XMLPull parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726239/how-i-get-attribute-using-by-xmlpull-parser)

```
//loop parser until you get Tag scale 
parser.getAttributeValue(null, "factor")
```